Automatically updating column value in database at a specific date Spring Data JPA
I have a Spring web application for an Android application that implements a platform for listing auctions, bidding, reviewing customers and so on.
The table 'Item' (MySQL) has a column called 'finalPrice' which indicates the final price the auction was closed at. If it's -1, then the auction didn't end yet. 0 means the auction ended with no buyers, and any other value means the auction ended with that final price.
In addition, the table has the columns auctionStart, auctionEnd that indicate the start and end of the auction in LocalDateTime (so finalPrice is -1 iff auctionEnd is after LocalDateTime.now())
I want the server to automatically change the value of column finalPrice to 0 or the price the auction ended at, at the LocalDateTime auctionEnd. How can I achieve this?
